# SAS: Unable to read dates in the program. How to fix it?

Tags: date, input, sas

Here's my code. I am unable to read the dates from the input, it keeps giving me incorrect format, I tried changing a few times to mmddyy10. mmddyy8. and others but it still does not read them in correctly.

```
data master_patients;
infile datalines;
input account_number name $8-16 address $17-34 date MMDDYYYY10. gender $1. 
insurance_code $49-51 updated_date mmddyyyy10.;
datalines;
620135 Smith     234 Aspen St.     12-21-1975 m CBC 02-16-1998
645722 Miyamoto   65 3rd Ave.      04-03-1936 f MCR 05-30-1999
645739 Jensvold  505 Glendale Ave. 06-15-1960 f HLT 09-23-1993
874329 Kazoyan   76-C La Vista     .          . MCD 01-15-2003
;
proc print data=master_patients;
run;
```

Could you please point out where I am going wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is your file actually fixed width? Usually specifying the columns on input statement isn't required. Also, try using an informat statement instead of specifying it on the input statement.

Comment: I am reading data from an example from a book, which is why the datalines option. As per the book this code should work just fine, but it isn't. Also I tried informat, it gives me the error "Informat MMDDYYYY was not found or could not be loaded."      and just for the heck of it, I tried changing it to mmddyy10. the last error went away and it gave me the error "Invalid data for dob in line 63 35-44.".

Comment: Well its possible that there is a typo in the data. What is the value of date in that record? Reading via datalines isn't the issue. Most likely the book had a well spaced, formatted code but when you copy and paste the data doesn't follow those rules anymore. You can see it with your third record where the address has an extra space. If you want to use the sample code make sure the spaces and alignment in the datalines is exactly like the book. You can also use the anydtdte format to read in dates.

Comment: Perfect, the use of anydtdte format solved the problem, I still do not understand what was going wrong with mmddyy10. but I guess bad formatting could be a problem. Either ways, thank you Reeza, for introducing me to anydtdte.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a specific informat, rather than anydtdte though it helps you get started. It will ensure that your data is correct.

```
data master_patients;
infile datalines;
informat date updated_date mmddyy10.;
format date updated_date date9.;
input account_number name $ 8-16 address $ 17-34 date gender $1. 
insurance_code $ 49-51 updated_date;
datalines;
620135 Smith     234 Aspen St.     12-21-1975 m CBC 02-16-1998
645722 Miyamoto  65 3rd Ave.       04-03-1936 f MCR 05-30-1999
645739 Jensvold  505 Glendale Ave. 06-15-1960 f HLT 09-23-1993
874329 Kazoyan   76-C La Vista     .          . MCD 01-15-2003
;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems.  First the informat name does not have 4 `Y`'s in it. Just 2.  Second you don't have the column pointer in the right place when you are trying to read 10 characters as a date so that you are getting a blank and then the first 9 characters of the date. SAS cannot represents dates in the second or third century AD.  Try `MDY(12,21,197)` and see what happens.

```
data master_patients;
infile datalines firstobs=2;
input account_number name $8-16 address $17-34 @36 date MMDDYY10.
      gender $1. insurance_code $49-51 @53 updated_date mmddyy10.
;
datalines;
----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+
620135 Smith     234 Aspen St.     12-21-1975 m CBC 02-16-1998
645722 Miyamoto   65 3rd Ave.      04-03-1936 f MCR 05-30-1999
645739 Jensvold  505 Glendale Ave. 06-15-1960 f HLT 09-23-1993
874329 Kazoyan   76-C La Vista     .          . MCD 01-15-2003
;
proc print data=master_patients;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

For modified list input for this problem.Just add ":" between variable name and informat.

```
data master_patients;
infile datalines;
input account_number name $8-16 address $17-34 date : mmddyy10. gender $1. 
insurance_code $49-51 updated_date : mmddyy10.;
datalines;
620135 Smith     234 Aspen St.     12-21-1975 m CBC 02-16-1998
645722 Miyamoto   65 3rd Ave.      04-03-1936 f MCR 05-30-1999
645739 Jensvold  505 Glendale Ave. 06-15-1960 f HLT 09-23-1993
874329 Kazoyan   76-C La Vista     .          . MCD 01-15-2003
;
proc print data=master_patients;
run;
```

Please note if you don't add ":" , just change mmddyy10. to anydtdte. , the data read into dataset may Not correct.